# ajax request not refired when returning to website when pressing browser 'Back' button

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I have a page that user can make changes to an item like changing title, description and etc, after user made the changes and they are saved, he can travel away from the website, then goes back using the 'Back' button and what he sees is the page actually before the changes he has made.

The reason for that, instead of actually making `GET` request for the item, Chrome returned request from the cache instead, you can see it in `Network` tab in the `Size` column as `(from cache)`.

One of the solutions that colleague of mine proposed is to append query parameter with some random integer to request, but it's kinda hacky.

Do you take care of this situation, if yes then how or why not?

Comment: either use pushStack api like history.js and/or a deep linking api like http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/